# How to use a different version of Zend Framework when using Zend Server

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server

I've installed Zend Server and Zend Framework is bundled with it. I've noticed that my new application uses the Zend Server version of Zend Framework (1.10), not the one I've pointed the /library/Zend to (1.9.6).

How can I override this default behavior? I'm afraid that if I upgrade Zend Server in the future it will automatically update Zend Framework and could break my application.

In summary, I have two versions of Zend Framework on the server the default one that is bundled with Zend Server (/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework) and another version that resides next to my appliation in (./library/Zend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little more digging and I'll answer my own question.

Since Zend Framework comes bundled with Zend Server CE, Zend Server CE has a default include_path of

`.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear`

So the Zend Application must see that instead of my `library/Zend` folder. To solve this just reset the include_path, at the top of your `index.php` file include this

`set_include_path('.');`

Then you want to make sure to have the Zend and ZendX folders in your `/library` folder of your application (or create symbolic links).